# Heroku PHP images not working when deployed?

Tags: php, html, heroku

I am having a problem where in my deployed PHP portfolio, the images are not rendering. It is returning a "404 not found" for all images. Problem is it works perfectly fine in my localhost with XAMPP. The images are not an absolute path, so i'm not sure why they would not be working. Does heroku place the index.php in a different directory after it's deployed? Here is what my directory looks like in VS code. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK6oD.png Does anyone know how to fix this? Index.php is in the root directory

Here is the src path in my html

```
<img class="project__img" src="img/thebarber.png" />
```

and here is my index.php which references the main.html

```
<?php include_once("main.html") ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the full path to the images?

Comment: I had my img folder in my .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this is happening. I had my img folder in my .gitignore and used git to deploy my application to heroku. As you can see the folder is blue, meaning its ignored.